# update state with selected item in flatlist

Tags: react-hooks, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

I have an array of images which I am able to display using flatlist. I wanted a feature where when you click on an image, it should be displayed in a separate view.

Below is my code snippet:

```
const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState(joy);
const [imageSet, setImageSet] = useState([joy,anger,concern,depression]);
return (
<SafeAreaView>
    <View style={{width: 100, height: 400}}>
      <Image style={{height: 50, width: 50}} source={selectedImage} />
    </View>
    <FlatList
    horizontal={true}
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    data={imageSet}
    renderItem={({item, index}) => (
        <View>
          <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={(item) => {
              setSelectedImage(item);    // trying to select the image here
              }}>
                <Image
                source={item}
                key={index}
                style={{
                  width: 60,
                  height: 60,
                  resizeMode: 'contain',
                }}
              />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )}
    />
</SafeAreaView>
);
```

But the images are not getting displayed when clicked on it. I am not able to figure out what the issue is. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I see your code is that you are passing item to setSelectedImage from the TouchableOpacity onPress which is undefined. Thats why image is not getting set into your state.

**Try this:**

**Before:**

```
<TouchableOpacity
   onPress={(item) => { <--- Remove this item!!
   setSelectedImage(item)}}>
```

**After:**

```
 <TouchableOpacity
       onPress={() => { 
       setSelectedImage(item)}}>
```